# matplotlib in pyqt6 app - plot doesn't autoscale when line data is updated

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt6

When I update the line data my plot does not resize even though autoscale is on. When I call the `updateData` function the data updates but the plot does not resize.

I've attempted to assert autoscale to true in multiple places with no succcess.
My code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtWidgets, QtCore
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

class MPWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.xdata = []
        self.ydata = []
        self.setMinimumWidth(600)
        self.setMinimumHeight(400)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.figure = Figure()
        canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        navtb = NavigationToolbar(canvas, self)
        layout.addWidget(navtb)
        layout.addWidget(canvas)

        gs = GridSpec(1, 2, width_ratios=[9, 1])
        self.axl = canvas.figure.add_subplot(gs[0])
        axr = canvas.figure.add_subplot(gs[1])

        x = np.arange(16384)
        y = 15000 * (np.sin(x/300) * np.exp(-x/2000))

        self.ll, = self.axl.plot(x, y, lw=0.5)
        self.axl.autoscale(enable=True)
        self.axl.autoscale()

        self.figure.tight_layout()
        
    def updateData(self, data):
        self.xdata, self.ydata = data
        self.ll.set_data(self.xdata, self.ydata)
        self.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.axl.autoscale()
        print(self.axl.get_autoscale_on())  # returns True
```